# Highcharts custom axis type (Weibull paper)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axes, weibull

I need to draw a chart with custom axis type.
Y axis should look like this: http://weibull.com/hotwire/issue8/rb8_7.gif
The equation of Y axis is: http://weibull.com/hotwire/issue8/rb8_3.gif
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [tickPostioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickPositioner) and develop your own functions for ticks.

Comment: The set up needed is about more than tick postions however.  It's the actual axis scaling that is affected for this type of display.

Comment: Yup, tickPostioner is not enough. I need to change axis scaling.

Comment: Scalling is based on ticks, please replicate your example as live demo which doesnt work.